# how to replace a string having single quote with some characters in C#

Tags: c#

I need a code which will search if a string contains single quote <kbd>'</kbd> before a character and that single quote should be replaced with two single quotes <kbd>'</kbd><kbd>'</kbd>.

example-:

```
input = "test's"
output = "test''s"

input = "test'"
output = "test'"

input = "test' "
output = "test' "
```

Comment: You mean `"` or `''`?

Comment: 'test''s' is double single quote not double quote which would be 'test"s'

Comment: i need ' ' instead of "

Comment: What do you mean by `input= 'test's'`? Do you mean `string input = "test's"`?

Comment: Hi,i mean string input = "test's"

Comment: Distinguish between two single quotes and one double quote with <kbd>'</kdb><kbd>'</kdb> and <kbd>"</kdb>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [positive lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to check if next character is a word:

```
string input = "test's";
var result = Regex.Replace(input, @"'(?=\w)", @"""");
```

This code uses regular expression to replace match in input string with double quotes. Pattern to match is `'(?=\w)`. It contains single quote and positive lookahead of next character (character itself will not be included in match). If match is found (i.e. input contains single quote followed by word character, then quote is replaced with given string (double quote in this case).

UPDATE: After your edit and comments, correct replacement should look like

```
var result = Regex.Replace(input, "'(?=[a-zA-Z])", "''");
```

Inputs:

```
"test's"
"test'"
"test' "
"test'42"
"Mr Jones' test isn't good - it's bad"
```

Outputs:

```
"test''s"
"test'"
"test' "
"test'42"
"Mr Jones' test isn''t good - it''s bad"
```

Comment: Hi,whatever you suggest is good but the characters before single quotes should be only alphabetic

Comment: @user3682903 then use `[a-zA-Z]` instead of `\w` - it will allow only alphabetic characters. Also if you need two single quotes instead of double quote (according to your update), then use `"''"` replacement string

Comment: Hello sir, sorry ! i need the output as 
output = test''s

Comment: Hi Sergey,i have some strings which has space after single quote.For example "test' " how to do with the space

Comment: The previous is removing space

Comment: @user3682903 just add space to chars which to look ahead `[a-zA-Z\s]`. If problem is solved, please take a [tour about StackOverflow site usage](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: please suggest me in the code var result = Regex.Replace(input, @"'(?=\w)", @""""); this is for all characters

Comment: @user3682903 I don't understand you. Use pattern above. Read some 10-minute regular expressions tutorial. Don not wait for copy-paste answer

Answer (score 0):

try this way

```
    String input = input.Replace("'","\"");
```

Comment: I don't know who upvoted this, but OP mentions _"if a string contains single quote ' **before a character** and that single quote should be replaced with **two single quotes** ''."_